# Color the textbox of a datepicker backend WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datepicker

I would like to change the color of the border datepicker , I saw solutions for changing in the xaml code, but would like to change it backend.

my code:

```
public static bool checkDate(DatePicker dpk)
{
   TextBox tb = (TextBox)dpk.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dpk);
   Border bd = (Border)tb.Template.FindName("Bd", tb);

   if (dpk.SelectedDate == null)
   {
       bd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
       return false;
   }

   bd.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
   return true;
}
```

I have no problems using

```
Border bd = (Border)tb.Template.FindName("Bd", tb);
```

for my other textbox etc.. But I am getting a nullException error when coloring, apparently it could not detect the border of the textbox used by the datepicker at this paricular line of code. Any advice?

Comment: Which line of code throws null exception ? I tried it and worked very well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you trying to do some data validation and highlight the missing field. The sample below should work; there's no need to look further than textbox part

```
    public static bool checkDate(DatePicker dpk)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)dpk.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dpk);

        if (dpk.SelectedDate == null)
        {
            tb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
            return false;
        }

        tb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        return true;
    }
```

In the future, try using http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to look at available parts/properties at runtime - it'll save you a ton of time

Comment: If you are setting: BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);, then why do you need BorderBrush = Brushes.Black; ? It has no meaning of setting BorderBrush if thickness is zero.

Comment: 'Cause I don't really know the original intention of the code? This is just a sample - you can achieve the same effect by manipulating either thickness or color with other attribute set to a fixed value someplace else; I chose to leave both for OP to choose

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The OP is asking he is not able to find some template parts from ControlTemplate and getting a null value.

Comment: No, the OP is saying that he 'would like to change the color of the border datepicker'. Which, incidentally, has zero thickness by default, so it won't be visible even if you do manage to change it to another color. Now, you don't know why he wants that and what he would do with the changed color afterwards; I've seen production code which was checking controls colors do determine whether input validation was successful or not. So, to illustrate that it is working I'm changing both thickness and color back and forth - it should be obvious what to remove when you integrate the sample

Comment: Have you read complete question ? I guess you missed this line "But I am getting a nullException error when coloring".